# phpword set image dimension in template

Tags: phpword

I'm using phpword to add text and images to a .docx.
I can add pictures that are identified by a placeholder just fine (for example ${TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT} ), but if I try to set dimensions it ignores them.
According to the documentation, this should work (template side):
${TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT:width=200:height=200:ratio=false}
but it doesn't, it only displays the picture with the default dimensions.
On the php side, I have:
$docx->setImageValue('TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT', $TA_Pics['TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT']);

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, with your code I get a resized image using an example png. Maybe you use a different image format that cannot be resized like this? Maybe you could try different image formats (png/jpg/gif/...) to see if it is a general problem. To check: the code that I used that worked was `$docx = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('inputTemplate.docx');
$TA_Pics = array('TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT' => 'example-image-a.png');
$docx->setImageValue('TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT', $TA_Pics['TM-TA-PICTURE-FRONT']);
$docx->saveAs("outputFile.docx");`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong phpword version (facepalm)... With the updated version it worked as in the documentation